# Prove that $x^{−1}Hx $ is a subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ and, for $x\in G$, let $x^{-1}ax$ denote the set $\{x^{−1}ax : a\in H\}$. Prove that $x^{−1}Hx$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: 1. Is it nonempty? 2. If it contains $a,b$, does it contain $a\cdot b$? 3. If it contains $a$, does it contain $a^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $H \ne \emptyset$.

1.)  Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $e \in H$ where $e \in G$ is the identity element.  Then $e = x^{-1} e x \in x^{-1}H x$.

2.)  If $y \in x^{-1}Hx$, then $y = x^{-1} z x$ for some $z \in H$.  Then $z^{-1} \in H$, since $H$ is a subgroup.  So $x^{-1} z^{-1} x \in x^{-1} H x$.  But $(x^{-1} z^{-1} x)(x^{-1} z  x) = e$ by a very easy computation, or $(x^{-1} z^{-1} x)y = e$;  this shows $y^{-1} = x^{-1} z^{-1} x \in x^{-1} H x$, so that $H$ contains the inverse of each of its elements.

3.)  If $k_1, k_2 \in x^{-1}Hx$, then $k_j = x^{-1} h_jx$ with $h_j \in H$ for $j = 1,2$, whence
$k_1 k_2 = (x^{-1} h_1 x)(x^{-1} h_2x) = x^{-1} h_1 
h_2 x \in x^{-1} H x \;$  since $h_1h_2 \in H$.  This shows $x^{-1}Hx$ is closed under the group operation.

(1)-(3) show that $x^{-1}Hx$ satisfies the group axioms under the associative operation inhereted from $G$, hence it is a subgroup.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Out of curiosity, what (exactly) do you mean by $H \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @ Dror:  well, *exactly* what I meant to say was that $H$ is not the empty set, so as a subgroup it actually *has* elements, putting a few more teeth in my subsequent discussion.   My understanding is that the group axioms make sense for $H = \emptyset$ *via* logical vacuity, so I wanted to rule that possibility out explicitly.  Does this make sense?  Of course, the empty subgroup would satisfy the conclusion of the problem statement as well, so perhaps my assumption $H \ne \emptyset$ is redundant.  What do you think?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (really): $H=\emptyset \implies 1_H \notin H \implies H$ is not a group.

Comment: @ Dror:  the more I think about this, the more I think you are right and that my assertion that $H \ne \emptyset$ is insurance of a sort against an event which will never occur!  As long, of course, that the definition of groups asserts that *there exists* $e \in G$ etc. etc. etc.  Oh well, at least ruling out a non-existent possibility leaves the rest of my argument intact!  Thanks for pointing this out.l  I will however, leave the seemingly innocuous assumption $H \ne \emptyset$ in my post so that people will know for a fact I am not perfect! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, $1\in H^x=x^{-1}Hx$ and so $x^{-1}Hx$ is not empty. Let $x^{-1}h_1x,x^{-1}h_2x\in x^{-1}Hx$. Then $x^{-1}h_1h_2x\in x^{-1}Hx$. Furthermore, $(x^{-1}h_1x)^{-1}= x^{-1}{h_1}^{-1}x\in x^{-1}h_1x$.

Answer (score 0):

$H \leq G \implies x^{-1}1_Gx=x^{-1}1_Hx \in x^{-1}Hx \implies x^{-1}Hx \neq \emptyset$

Now, let $x^{-1}hx,x^{-1}jx \in x^{-1}Hx$.  So:
$$x^{-1}hx(x^{-1}jx)^{-1}=x^{-1}hxx^{-1}j^{-1}x=x^{-1}hj^{-1}x \in x^{-1}Hx.$$
And the subgroup criterion is fulfilled.